# NSManagedObject not saving

Tags: cocoa, core-data

Apologies if this has been answered before but I can't find a reference.  I am trying Cocoa / obj-c for the first time.  I am trying to knock up an app which will sync with a remote backup system via http (a la s3) and am stumbling around some fundamental core data issues.

I have created an entity and can invoke this without issues.  The problem arrives when I call save on NSManagedObjectContext.

I am not going to include all methods involved in invoking the object context / model as the log output should (I think) verify that it is working as expected.

Best described with code and appropriate log entries.

---

**First, for illustration, I am invoking the managed object: **

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {

    if (managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return managedObjectModel;
    }

    managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil] retain];    
    NSLog(@"The managed object model is defined as follows:\n%@",     managedObjectModel);
    return managedObjectModel;
}
```

**And the log output from the above NSLog:**

```
2011-09-06 14:31:38.322 TryAgain[18885:a0f] The managed object model is defined as follows:
(<NSManagedObjectModel: 0x2000e2b00>) isEditable 1, entities {
        BackupItinerary = "(<NSEntityDescription: 0x20020e9e0>) name BackupItinerary, managedObjectClassName NSManagedObject, renamingIdentifier 
            BackupItinerary, isAbstract 0, superentity name (null), properties {\n    \"file_url\" = \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x2000faec0>), name
            file_url, isOptional 0, isTransient 0, entity BackupItinerary, renamingIdentifier file_url, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n),
            versionHashModifier (null), attributeType 700 , attributeValueClassName NSString, defaultValue (null)\";\n    \"last_sync_date\" =
            \"(<NSAttributeDescription: 0x2000faf60>), name last_sync_date, isOptional 1, isTransient 0, entity BackupItinerary, renamingIdentifier
            last_sync_date, validation predicates (\\n), warnings (\\n), versionHashModifier (null), attributeType 900 , attributeValueClassName
            NSDate, defaultValue (null)\";\n}, subentities {\n}, userInfo {\n}, versionHashModifier (null)";
}, fetch request templates {
}
```

**This looks so have been successful.  No exceptions thrown, or warnings.**

Now, the actual problem arrives when I call save on the object context.  I have a NSOpenPanel which allows for picking dir / files to backup (all hooked up and working fine).  Upon the user selecting a dir/file I want to set the value, so I:

```
NSArray *paths = [panel URLs];
NSURL *filePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
[directories addObject:filePath];
[directories setArray:[[NSSet setWithArray: directories] allObjects]];  
NSEntityDescription *BackupItineraryEntity = [[self.managedObjectModel  entitiesByName] objectForKey:@"BackupItinerary"];
NSManagedObject* BackupItinerary = [[NSManagedObject alloc]
                    initWithEntity:BackupItineraryEntity
    insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[BackupItinerary setValue:[filePath absoluteString] forKey:@"file_url"];
NSLog(@"entity:\n%@", BackupItinerary);
```

**And the call to NSLog says (having selected /Users/rick/selenium2-webdriver/):**

```
2011-09-06 14:31:38.328 TryAgain[18885:a0f] entity:
<NSManagedObject: 0x200216c80> (entity: BackupItinerary; id: 0x200090860 <x-coredata:///BackupItinerary/t0C005B39-D185-454B-B364-31314EEB10F02> ;     
        data: {
            "file_url" = "file://localhost/Users/rick/selenium2-webdriver/";
            "last_sync_date" = nil;
        })
```

**So, the file_url seems to be populated then, yes? But when I:**

```
NSError *error;
if (![[self managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@, %@", error, [error userInfo],[error localizedDescription]);
}
```

**The log says:**

```
2011-09-06 14:31:38.330 TryAgain[18885:a0f] Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1570 UserInfo=0x2000cc4e0 "file_url is a required  
value.", {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "file_url is a required value.";
    NSValidationErrorKey = "file_url";
    NSValidationErrorObject = "<NSManagedObject: 0x20020f660> (entity: BackupItinerary; id: 0x20008faa0 <x-coredata:///BackupItinerary/t0C005B39
            D185-454B-B364-31314EEB10F03> ; data: {\n    \"file_url\" = nil;\n    \"last_sync_date\" = nil;\n})";
}, file_url is a required value.
```

---

So basically:

I can, it seems (?), invoke the an entity and set a value on it, but when it comes to saving it the values is not set.  The above code is executed inline and I am using garbage collection.

Feels like a total newb school boy error issue but for the life of me I can't see what I am missing having gone over the docs, highlevel tutorials and example code.

Pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at two different managed object instances. The instance that has its `file_url` property set is `<NSManagedObject: 0x200216c80>` while the one that reports the error is `<NSManagedObject: 0x20020f660>`.

Somewhere, you are inserting an instance but not giving it a `file_url` value. In the code given, it might happen if the user selects cancel in the NSOpenPanel.

Comment: OK, good pointer on object ids - thanks.  This is all a bit new, but fun, for me!Not related to user clicking cancel as the above code is wrapped in an if block detecting NSOKButton.  However I was changing the scope of BackupItinerary in another method when trying to populate the list of stored directories.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the output of your NSLog's, I'd say that `BackupItinerary` object is different when saving your context. Check this output on different occasions:

When inserting and setting the value:

```
entity:
<NSManagedObject: 0x200216c80>
```

When saving:

```
NSValidationErrorObject = "<NSManagedObject: 0x20020f660>
```

As you can see the addresses of instances differ, hence you're inserting one, but saving the other instance. Hope this helps.